# Cant upload a file into my Firebase Storage - error 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a file (an image) into my firebase storage and I get this error:

> POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com... 403 (Forbidden)

This is my code:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/images/' + file.name);
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
// Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
// Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
}, function(error) {
// Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
// Handle successful uploads on complete
// For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
});
```

I do not know if the code is related to my problem, but I put it anyway.
I'm wondering if could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: it would typically tell you there was a permission issue in the error

Answer (score 3):

An 403() error means that you do not have permission to upload to firebase storage, probably because the default permission rules needs you to be authenticated. To fix it, just change the rules in the firebase console :)

For example, to give permission to unauthorized users, change the middle line to: `allow read, write: if true;`